# Align a input field within a table cell

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to get my input field to align to the left of the table cell. I have tried float and that throws everything out of whack. The cells width are being created dynamically so I can't add a padding to the right to push it to the left. I am also using jQuery if there is some way to use it.

**UPDATE:**
I have tried the suggestions that have been offered. Here is a [link](http://practiscore.com/match-results/uuid?uuid=500AA6CE-49AB-4447-A6DD-75F0A295E4E4&page=matchCombined) to my page where I am having the problem. The input boxes at the footer of the table I can't get to align left. CSS is not my strong suite.

Comment: can you not use align="left" for any reason?

Comment: @Elen — Deprecated, obsolete, very last millenium.

Comment: Use a DOM inspector to check the `<th>` elements in the footer, then look at the padding.

Comment: There is a padding being added to the <th>in the <tfoot>. This is causing the cells to align adjacent to each other. Since the <input> is 100% of the <th> it expands to the full width of the <th> minus the <th> padding. Replace the padding with a margin and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All else being equal, an input in a table data cell *will* align to the left by default.

If it is a table heading cell, then apply `text-align: left` to the cell.

If that doesn't work, then stop doing whatever it is you are doing that is making it something other than left aligned.

Comment: I tried to apply your suggestion but it still won't move. I updated my post with a link to my page. If you can look at it and suggest what to remove from my CSS.

Comment: There are lots of inputs on that page. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: And why on earth are they in table header cells? They aren't headings.

Comment: Any why to you have a table with a tfoot but no tbody?

Comment: Fix your [machine detectable errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpractiscore.com%2Fmatch-results%2Fuuid%3Fuuid%3D500AA6CE-49AB-4447-A6DD-75F0A295E4E4%26page%3DmatchCombined&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: All of them have the problem of aligning to the right. As for them being <th> I was following the examples from the jquery plugin ~ datatables. I will have to check and see if it needs to be a <th> for the plugin to work. That did seem a little odd to me as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td style="text-align: left">your input fields</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achoplish this by using css text-align: left;

In html `<td style="text-align: left;" >Your stuff</td>`